# SPM trouble fetching through XCode refs/remotes/origin/dev not found

Tags: xcode, git, swift-package-manager

I made a new repo and I'm fetching through SPM and XCode and I keep getting this message

"Error while fetching remote repositoryssh://git@someBitbucketurl.git: An unknown error occurred. reference 'refs/remotes/origin/dev' not found (-1)"

Did I mess up setting up the repo? I have to delete a bunch of stuff to get it to update properly.

I checked my git repo and I have a dev branch set as a default. I'm not sure what I should do to fix the dev branch.

Please help.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I also get this, and am not sure if it is related to my  Github personal access token in Xcode / SSH

Comment: I don't remember, it was something nonsensical, like resetting my dependency 5 times, or nuking my repo. Sorry I couldn't be of more help. I think part of it might have been because it was a new repo that did not have it's master and dev branches set up properly.